# How to configure Helidon application to use in-memory database for integration tests?

Tags: maven, jpa, junit, persistence, helidon

We are setting up a Helidon MP application that connects to a SQL database and exposes some endpoints for CRUD operations. I am facing issues when implementing the integration tests. Our objective is to have the application use the SQL database, but when running the tests use an in-memory database.

1. I've used this type of implementation on others frameworks and programing languages. The initial solution was to access the dependency injection container and change the configuration of the ORM (hibernate in this case) to use an in-memory database. Unfortunately I did not manage to do this.
2. The second approach was to configure another **persistence.xml** file in the test folder, that would override the one from main folder. Using on each of them a different jta-data-source, I would be able to configure separate connection credentials. I found out that this causes a ambiguous dependency and would fail.

content of src/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml

```
<persistence>

    <persistence-unit name="dservice" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>dsource</jta-data-source>
        <class>.....</class>
        .
        .
        .
        <class>.....</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

content of test/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml

```
<persistence>

    <persistence-unit name="dservice" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>dsource_test</jta-data-source>
        <class>.....</class>
        .
        .
        .
        <class>.....</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.sql-load-script-source" value="META-INF/init_script.sql"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

content of src/resources/META-INF/microprofile-config.properties

```
# used for build
oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource.dsource.URL=jdbc:oracle:something
oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource.dsource.connectionFactoryClassName=oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource
oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource.dsource.user=some_user
oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource.dsource.password=some_password

# used for in-memory testing
oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource.dsource_test.URL=jdbc:h2:mem:depServerDb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource.dsource_test.connectionFactoryClassName=org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource
oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource.dsource_test.user=db_user
oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource.dsource_test.password=user_password
```

3. I added in **main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml** another persistence unit with a different name and try to create the entity manager manually using Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory() and have a provider class to access the entity manager. Unfortunately this attempt also failed.

content of src/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml

```
<persistence>

    <persistence-unit name="dservice" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>dsource</jta-data-source>
        <class>.....</class>
        .
        .
        .
        <class>.....</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>


    <persistence-unit name="dservice_test" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>dsource_test</jta-data-source>
        <class>.....</class>
        .
        .
        .
        <class>.....</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.sql-load-script-source" value="META-INF/init_script.sql"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

4. **I ended up with a solution** that I am not satisfied with. I kept the persistence.xml from scenario 3 and added a entity manager provider class in which I inject two entity managers, one for each persistence unit. In the test class I added a @AddConfig(key = "app.testing", value = "true"). This will make my entity manager provider to deliver the entity manager *"depservice"* when the application is running and *"depservice-test"* when I run *"mvn test"* command.

content of provider class

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class PersistenceUnitProvider {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "dservice")
    private EntityManager em_application;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "dservice_test")
    private EntityManager em_test;

    private String testing = false;

    @Inject
    public PersistenceUnitProvider(@ConfigProperty(name = "app.testing") String testing){
        this.testing = testing;
    }

    public EntityManager getPersistenceUnit(){
        if(this.testing == "true"){
            return em_test;
        }
        return em_application;
    }
}
```

content of junit test class that will change app.testing property to true and use in-memory database

```
@HelidonTest
@AddConfig(key = "app.testing", value = "true")
class MainTest {
    .
    ..
    ...
    ....
}
```

The issue is that this makes the application establish two connections when it's run or tested. Is there a better way to achieve this?

..............................................................................................................................................

UPDATE:
Following the solution Laird mentioned in the accepted answer, we are using the maven build process, that has **phase triggers** to add whatever config files needed to change the behavior of the helidon application.

We created a folder to store all the config files used for development, test and production, with the following structure:

```
_config
   development
       (files that use a local SQL database)
   tests
       (files that use a in memory database)
   production
       (files that use a development SQL database)
```

In the pom.xml file we switch the config files as needed for the different phases

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources-dev</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/META-INF</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>_config/development</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>    
            </configuration>
        </execution>

        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources-test</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/META-INF</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>_config/tests</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources-packaging</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/META-INF</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>_config/production</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This will enable us, when we run "helidon dev", to use a localhost database. When we execute the tests, use a in-memory database. And when we package the application and want to run it on a server somewhere, use whatever database we need it to.

Comment: use test containers

Comment: Did you try having 2 copies of microprofile-config-properties? One in the tests folder and other under main source tree. You could then use the same pool datasource configuration keys and persistence untils in both tests and production but just change the values in the tests copy of properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many, many, many things going on here. I'll try to keep it short; a full JPA tutorial is beyond the scope of this question and this website.

The short answer is: (1) in JPA, a `persistence.xml` is definitionally environment-specific, and (2) `persistence.xml`s don't "override" each other.  When seen this way, the problem reduces to: I want two environments in the same project and can't figure out how to turn them on and off selectively.

There are a variety of (non-Helidon-specific) ways you can do this sort of thing:

1. Use the `maven-resources-plugin` to defer copying `src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml` into `target/classes/META-INF/` until after unit tests have run (so exclude `persistence.xml` from [`<resources>`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#resources) in your `pom.xml` and then bind the [`maven-resources-plugin:copy-resources` goal](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/copy-resources-mojo.html) to the [`prepare-package` phase](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.6/maven-core/lifecycles.html#default_Lifecycle).  Now `src/test/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml` will be in effect at unit test time, and your (untested) `src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml` will be the one you deploy with.
2. Do amazing things with MicroProfile Config configuration profiles **if the only thing you need to change is data source information**, which is already external to a container-mode-JPA `persistence.xml` file, but from your example it seems that you need to change `<property>` elements as well.
3. Recognize that since `persistence.xml`s are inherently environment-specific, just don't include a `src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml` at all in your library project, since a library project, by definition, is supposed to be used in a *variety* of environments.  Instead, place a `persistence.xml` in its own "thin" project and combine *that* project with your library project to form an application.  You can of course test these combinations in all sorts of other ways.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend against adding test code to production bits, like you are doing with em_application and em_test. This may look simple at start but quickly go out of hand before you realize it.

Instead, try to retain only one line of code for testing and production. Have a single JPA persistence unit (em_application) in your PersistenceUnitProvider, persistence.xml and microprofile-config.properties. Stick to OracleDialect in test as well. Make a second copy of your META-INF/microprofile-config.properties under your JUnit test directory and retain the H2 configuration in the test copy. You would additionally have to shift your init_script.sql to the H2 connection URL to orchestrate the setup, since persistence.xml can no longer carry H2 configuration.

The HelidonTest application should pick up the test copy of mp-config properties file and the persistence until would automatically now work with H2.